# Apply a function to objects in my global environment R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

This code chunk creates a 10 objects based of length of alpha.

```
alpha <- seq(.1,1,by=.1)

for (i in 1:length(alpha)){
  assign(paste0("list_ts_ses_tune", i),NULL)

}
```

How do I put each function into the new list_ts_ses_tune1 ... null objects I've created? Each function puts in a list, and works if I set list_ts_ses_tune1 <- lapply ...

```
for (i in 1:length(alpha))
  {
  list_ts_ses_tune[i] <- lapply(list_ts, function(x) 
forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=alpha[i]))) 
  list_ts_ses_tune[i] <- lapply(list_ts_ses_tune[i], "[",  c("mean"))
}
```

Maybe this is a better way to do this? I need each individual output in a list of values.

Edit:

```
for (i in 1:length(alpha))
 {
 list_ts_ses_tune[[i]] <- lapply(list_ts[1:(length(list_ts)/2)], 
function(x) 
forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=alpha[i]))) 
 list_ts_ses_tune[[i]] <- lapply(list_ts_ses_tune[[i]], "[",  c("mean"))

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return all the objects into a `list`

```
mget(ls(pattern = '^list_ts_ses_tune\\d+'))
```

---

Also, the NULL `list` can be created more easily instead of 10 objects in the global environment

```
list_ts_ses_tune <- vector('list', length(alpha))
```

Now, we can just use the OP's code

```
for (i in 1:length(alpha))
  {
  list_ts_ses_tune[[i]] <- lapply(list_ts, function(x) 
forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=alpha[i]))) 
  
}
```

If we want to create a single data.frame

```
for(i in seq_along(alpha)) {
    list_ts_ses_tune[[i]] <- data.frame(Mean = do.call(rbind, lapply(list_ts, function(x)
           forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=alpha[i]))$mean)))
}
```

Comment: This solution is amazing. Thanks

Comment: Ok I will. One question to follow up, if I wanted to loop through this for each element and I want to put into a dataframe as a column? For example list_ts_ses_tune[[1]][[1]] is one output, and I want all of the values of list_ts_ses_tune[[1]][[2]], etc.. then list_ts_ses_tune[[2]][[1]] etc all as unique dataframe columns. How would I do that?

Comment: @chriswang123 are you trying to extract the `mean` column and create a data.frame

Comment: Yes, to access each output i need to do list_ts_ses_tune[[1]][[1]], where [[1]] =alpha and the 2nd [[1]] is the mean column. I want all of the mean outputs into one dataframe

Comment: This is almost perfect. The problem is the dfs are 8 rows by 24 . I want it to be 24 rows by length(alpha). Also is there a way to put the means into an existing dataframe?

Comment: You can just transpose by `t` or use `do.call(cbind`

Comment: Okay I tried both solutions, and I prefer the one we don't create a data.frame directly. list_ts_ses_tune[[i]][[j]]. I want to add the means like this to an EXISTING DATAFRAME in a loop. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: @chriswang123 in the code which one is existing dataframe.  Sorry, there is some confusion in the code

Comment: I don't have a dataframe with data in the example. list_ts_ses_tune[[i]][[j]] is a vector of mean with length of 24. My dataframe will have 24 rows and any# of columns. I want to create new columns in said dataframe with the vectors of mean length 24 (matches the rows)

Comment: @chriswang123 then you need need `do.call(cbind,  list_ts_ses_tune[[i]])`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply accomplish everything by doing:

```
library(forecast)
list_ts_ses_tune <- Map(function(x) 
                       lapply(alpha, function(y)forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=y))['mean']), list_ts)
```

Comment: I get this error ," longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter". list_ts is a list of time series, which in my data only has 8 elements